# An advanced-algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

A set $K$ consists of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ invertible matrixes such that $\left| K \right| = m$ and its elements are $A_i$, $i=1,2,\cdots,m$. If $\forall {A_i}{\kern 1pt} ,{A_j} \in K$, $A_iA_j$ and ${A_i}^{ - 1}\in K$, and $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {tr({A_i}) = 0} $, then show that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {{A_i} = 0} $.

Comment: Even after much squinting, I have failed in finding a question mark...

Comment: @J.M., the question mark has been absorbed in "if..., then" with a missing phrase "show that" or something alike :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first note that $$A_iA_k=A_jA_k\Leftrightarrow A_i=A_j$$ by right multiplication  by $A_k^{-1}$ which is an element of $K$.

Therefore we can say that, if $X=\sum_{i=1}^m A_i,$ $$XA_j=X,\quad\forall j\in\{1,\dotso,m\},$$ therefore $$X\left(\sum_{i=1}^m A_i\right)=mX\Rightarrow X^2-mX=0.$$
It then follows that the eigenvalues of $X$ are either $0$ or $m>0$, but since $$\text{tr}(X)=0,$$ then all the eigenvalues are $0$. Therefore $X$ is nilpotent, i.e. there exists $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $$X^k=0.$$ But then, exploiting the fact (already hinted above) that $$X^k=m^{k-1}X,$$ we get $$m^{k-1}X=0$$ an then finally $$X=0,$$ as we wanted. Hope it is correct. regards.

Comment: Nice proof, the argument that $XA_j=X$ for all $j$ is particularly clever.